# Unique visitors and total visitors in a month

Tags: experience-analytics

How can i retrieve, count of unique visitors and total visitors who have visited a Sitecore site in a month ,  using experience database.

Answer (score 4):

To get the total number of visitors for a month you can use the MongoDb data. Here is an example:

```
//Connecting to the Analytics DB
var driver = Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDriver.FromConnectionString("analytics");

//Building our query
var builder = new QueryBuilder();
var filter = builder.And(
    builder.GTE(_ => _.StartDateTime, 
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)), 
                builder.EQ(_ => _.SiteName, 
                siteName.ToLower())); 

//Retrieving data from the "Interactions" collection
var interactions = driver.Interactions.FindAs(filter)
```

That should give you all visits for the last 30 days. It should give you a starting point to then calculate unique visitors etc...

Code sample taken from this blog post: http://sitecorepro.blogspot.com.by/2015/06/starting-with-sitecore-analytics.html by **Konstantin Cherkasov**